# send sms using codeingiter, error "Some Parameter are missing : sender"

Tags: php, codeigniter, sms

This is my controller in codeigniter.

I am able to print print post data but when i am sending, this error comes :

"Some Parameter are missing : sender"

```
public function sendsms(){

    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $message = $this->input->post('message');

    $data = $this->input->post();

    $authKey = "********";
    unset($data['submit']);
    $mobilenumber = implode('', $data['mobile']);

    $arr = str_split($mobilenumber, "10");

    $numbers = implode(",", $arr);

    $senderId = "REL";
    $route = 4;

    $postData = array(
        'authkey' => $authKey,
        'mobiles' => $numbers,
        'message' => $message,
        'senderId' => $senderId,
        'route' => $route
            );

    $url = "********";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));


    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Some Parameter are missing : sender` this is not a programming bug. It is the response coming from your SMS API. So just check the documentation of your SMS API and see what is the meaning of this message. I think you are missing some required parameter during API call.

Comment: Thank You for your response, i got my mistake